# How to get average CPU temperature from bash?

Tags: linux, bash, cpu, temperature

How can I get the average CPU temperature from bash on Linux?  Preferably in degrees Fahrenheit.  The script should be able to handle different numbers of CPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like so:

**Installation**

```
sudo apt install lm-sensors
sudo sensors-detect --auto
```

**get_cpu_temp.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. get temperature

## a. split response
## Core 0:       +143.6°F  (high = +186.8°F, crit = +212.0°F)
IFS=')' read -ra core_temp_arr <<< $(sensors -f | grep '^Core\s[[:digit:]]\+:') #echo "${core_temp_arr[0]}"

## b. find cpu usage
total_cpu_temp=0
index=0
for i in "${core_temp_arr[@]}"; do :
    temp=$(echo $i | sed -n 's/°F.*//; s/.*[+-]//; p; q')
    let index++
    total_cpu_temp=$(echo "$total_cpu_temp + $temp" | bc)
done
avg_cpu_temp=$(echo "scale=2; $total_cpu_temp / $index" | bc)

## c. build entry
temp_status="CPU: $avg_cpu_temp F"
echo $temp_status

exit 0
```

**output**

CPU: 135.50 F

Comment: `sensors` output is not stable, it can change depending on configuration. In scripts, I think I would suggest to use `sensors -u` output.

Answer (score 1):

You can also read CPU temperatures directly from `sysfs` (path may differ from machine/OS to machine/OS though):

#### Bash:

```sh
temp_file=$(mktemp -t "temp-"$(date +'%Y%m%d@%H:%M:%S')"-XXXXXX")
ls $temp_file
while true; do
    cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp | tr '\n' ' ' >> "$temp_file"
    printf "\n" >> $temp_file
    sleep 2
done
```

If you're a fish user, you may add a function to your config dir, let's say: `~/.config/fish/functions/temp.fish`

#### Fish

```
function temp
    set temp_file (mktemp -t "temp-"(date +'%Y%m%d@%H:%M:%S')"-XXXXXX")
    ls $temp_file
    while true
        cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp | tr '\n' ' ' >> "$temp_file"
        printf "\n" >> $temp_file
        sleep 2
    end
end
```

#### Example

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I was unaware of those files.  What units are those numbers in?  Not Celsius.

Comment: `for e in $(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp); do
        printf "%s " $e` just `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp | tr '\n' ' ' >> "$temp_file"`. From the man page: tempfile is deprecated; you should use mktemp(1) instead.

Comment: @xinthose no problem. Those are Celsius times 1000.